# Qual è il significato di "affranto" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> Una freddezza *affranta* le schiude, su queste basi, un avvenire solitario e rassegnato di reproba che sarà almeno il suo regno, come son suoi questo buio, questo letto dove s'è nascosta e il sonno che nessuno può impedirle di simulare, se un lume volesse forzarlo.

Ho cercato il significato di "affranto" in alcuni dizionari e ho visto che può significare *stremato, logorato, abbattuto, sfinito*. Tuttavia, non capisco il senso di "freddezza affranta" nel brano precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Affranto*, in questo contesto, potrebbe essere utilizzato come [sinonimo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/affranto_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/) di *sconsolato*:

> 2. [che è in una condizione di abbattimento spirituale] ≈ abbattuto, accasciato, afflitto, avvilito, demoralizzato, desolato, prostrato, sconfortato, **sconsolato**, travagliato, triste. ↔ contento, felice, rasserenato, soddisfatto, sollevato.

Se dunque s'intende "freddezza" come "mancanza di entusiasmo" (cfr. *[Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/freddezza/)*), *freddezza affranta* potrebbe essere utilizzata per designare una condizione di impassibilità inconsolabile e che apparentemente non mostra vie d'uscita.